# How will one of the products of disjoint cycles look like

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $A_n$

What are the possibilities for an element of $N$?

1.If $N$ contains a 3 cycle then $N=A_n$

2.If an element of $N$ is of the form $\sigma \mu$ where $\sigma $ and $\mu$ are disjoint and either $\sigma $ or $\mu$ has length greater than 3 then also $N=A_n$

Suppose $N$ does not have elements of this form then if I write an element of $N$ as a product of disjoint cycles,what will it look like?

**According to J.B.fraleigh ;**
At least one of the products of disjoint cycles should contain 2 $3-$ cycles or $1$ $3$ cycle or no $3$ cycle .I cant justify this claim why is this true?

Ant help

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking: Presumably you're aware that [$A_{3}$ and $A_{n}$ for $n \geq 5$ are simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) (i.e., have no proper, non-trivial normal subgroup), and that the set of elements of order one or two in $A_{4}$ _is_ normal...? (Or are you trying to _prove_ $A_{n}$ is simple for $n \geq 5$?)

Comment: I want to justify the fact one of the products should contain 2 3-cycles or 1 or none.why will the cases exhaust all possible cases?

Comment: Am I clear @user86418

Comment: It appears you're trying to prove $A_{n}$ ($n \geq 5$) is simple by showing that if $N$ is a normal subgroup containing an element of a certain form, then $N = A_{n}$. So you eliminate cases 1 and 2; now you're asking "what will [an element of $N$] look like?" Not sure if you're: (i) Assuming $N$ is a normal subgroup, and trying to determine what kinds of element $N$ might contain; (ii) Trying to make a systematic logical enumeration of permutation types, and then show that if a normal subgroup $N$ contains such an element, $N = A_{n}$. But I'll post some hints/ideas....

Answer (score 0):

Here are some (presumably known) facts:

- Every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.
- Disjoint cycles commute. In particular, if $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are disjoint cycles, then $(\sigma\mu)^{m} = \sigma^{m} \mu^{m}$ for all integers $m$.
- A $k$-cycle is even (as a permutation) if and only if the length $k$ is odd (as an integer).
- The sign of a permutation is the "sum" of the signs of its disjoint cycle factors (e.g., even composed with odd is odd).

Particularly, a permutation $\sigma$ is even if and only if the representation of $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles contains an *even number of even-length cycles* (zero, two, four, etc.).

Fraleigh's hint seems to refer to permutations that are (or that contain) a product of three or more disjoint cycles, and perhaps to the fact that if a normal subgroup $N$ contains a product of three $3$-cycles, then $N$ contains a product of fewer than three $3$-cycles.

The point of the hint appears to be this: Suppose
$$
\sigma = (1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5\ 6)(7\ 8\ 9) = \alpha_{1} \alpha_{2} \alpha_{3} \in N.
$$
The permutation $\tau = (4\ 5)(7\ 8)$ is even, so
$$
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (1\ 2\ 3)(5\ 4\ 6)(8\ 7\ 9) = \alpha_{1} \alpha_{2}^{-1} \alpha_{3}^{-1} \in N.
$$
Consequently, the product
$$
\sigma(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}) = \alpha_{1}^{2}
$$
(a $3$-cycle) is in $N$.

You can play the same game for arbitrary products of three (or more) $3$-cycles, with the end result that: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $A_{n}$, and if $\sigma$ is an element of $N$ whose representation as a product of disjoint cycles contains three or more $3$-cycles, then $N$ contains an element $\sigma'$ whose representation as a product of disjoint cycles contains fewer than three $3$-cycles.